# Solaris/Linux - tput command + create bold text

Tags: linux, bash, solaris, ksh

How do I bold the "Date & Time" numbers from the following file with the [tput](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tput) command (I have a Solaris machine)?

For example, I want to bold only the "24-09-2009 16:17:45", etc. for all other date and time.

The tput will write in my ksh script.

```
  TIMESTAMP               SET_ID TELEPHONE                    No TYPE
  ------------------- ---------- -------------------- ---------- ------------------

  24-09-2009 16:17:45          0 33633333333                  20 other_mms_phone
  24-09-2009 17:45:07          0 33644444444                  20 other_mms_phone
  07-10-2009 10:45:49          0 12312312312                  20 legacyphone
  07-10-2009 11:46:38          0 59320000043                  20 other_mms_phone
```

try solution  by this - but not work on my solaris machine ?

```
       awk 'NR>2' output.csv | sed 's/^\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{19\}\)/\1'$(tput rmso ) '/'
```

Illegal variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk 'NR>2' inputfile.txt |\
sed 's/^\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{19\}\)/\1'$(tput smso)'\2'$(tput rmso)'/'
```

1. `awk` skips the header,
2. sed picks all character up to character 2 and puts them in group `\1`, and the next 19 characters and puts them in group `\2`, and then inserts `tput smso` and `tput smso` (start and end bold according to `man tput`) before and after group 2.

Comment: see my update in my question ( i get error - Illegal variable name.)

Comment: Yeah, well, you haven't copied my command. The error you get is because of the added spaces in your try (specifically the second), but you are also completely missing parts of the `sed` expression. Just copy my line and it will work.

Comment: @yael: forgot to highlight. Read above comment.